# Batch Modulus Problems

Tags: windows, batch-file, modulus

For an assignment, we are tasked to make a FOR loop in Batch from , and calculate a total from (1 to 100 mod 5) + 3. I'm stuck and could use some help.

```
@ECHO off

:MAIN
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (

SET A=%%i
SET B=5
SET /A C=A%%B
IF %C%==0 GOTO TOTAL

:TOTAL
SET NUM=C+3

)
```

Thanks So Much!

Comment: Just glancing at it, I see at least three things wrong with that code. Which part, specifically, are you having problems with?

Answer (score 4):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:MAIN
SET /a C=0
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (
SET /A C+=%%i
)
SET /a NUM=C %% 5 +3
ECHO num=%num%

GOTO :EOF
```

First problem : without `setlocal`, your environment persists between runs. Consequently, any value that you have `set` in any variables `a` `b` `c` `num` (batch is mostly case-insensitive) will become the starting values when you next run the batch within the same `cmd` session.

Including the `setlocal` means that any changes you make to the environment will be discarded when the batch ends.

Next problem: It's unclear whether you mean ((sum of 1 to 100) mod 5) + 3 or (sum of 1 to (100 mod 5)) + 3. I've assumed the former since `100 mod 5` = 0, and the sum from 1 to 0 makes little sense (to me.)

Next : A `for` loop cannot contain a label within the "block" (a parenthesised sequence of lines) as it terminates the block.

Next : The entire block is first `parsed` (checked for syntactic validity) and then executed. Batch replaces any `%var%` within the block with its value at **parse time** so `%C%` would be replaced by *nothing* since `c` is not defined when the `for` command is reached. Consequently, the command is replaced by

```
IF ==0 GOTO TOTAL
```

So batch objects as an `if` statement should read `if string1 operator string2 action`. It therefore sees `goto` where it expects an operator (like `==`) and produces an error message.

Since you don't absolutely **know** that any variable will not be defined, it's prudent to initialise your variables (hence the `SET /a C=0` in the replacement I've posted.)

Next - why do you want to break out of the loop if `c` becomes `0`? There seems to be no **reason** to do this. It is possible - but you'd need to use `delayedexpansion` to access the value within the loop as it varies (the **run-time** value.) This is way beyond what you have kearned so far, but if you're interested, there are hundreds of SO articles on `delayedexpansion`.

So - the way the code I've posted works is to set `c` to 0 so that it is set to a known value, just in case it happens to be something else at the start.

Then, for each value of `%%i` from 1 to 100, add `%%i` to `c`. Another valid way would be

```
 set /a c=c+%%i
```

Then set `num` to (c mod 5) and add 3, then display it.

Batch assigns `%` (the `mod` operator) a higher precedence that `+`, so the adding is performed after the mod operation. You could also group the elements:

```
 set /a num=(c %% 5) + 3
```

The spaces are merely for readability.

`%%` is required because the `%` needs to be `escaped` - that is, its special meaning in batch needs to be turned off, so the `%` is preceded by another `%` because `%` is the escape character for `%`. If you need to escape other characters, you need to use *caret* (`^`) instead.